# How to get the value form the following Json response in android

Tags: android, json

I get the Json response like this,

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "General Knowlege Questions",
        "description": "This questions will test your General ",
        "questions": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "text": "Who invented the BALLPOINT PEN?",
                "type": "2",
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "text": "Biro Brothers"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "2",
                        "text": "Waterman Brothers"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "3",
                        "text": "Bicc Brothers"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "4",
                        "text": "Write Brothers "
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "text": "What J. B. Dunlop invented?",
                "type": "2",
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "id": "5",
                        "text": "Pneumatic rubber tire"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "6",
                        "text": "Automobile wheel rim"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "7",
                        "text": "Rubber boot"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "8",
                        "text": "Model airplanes"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "text": "Which scientist discovered the radioactive element radium?",
                "type": "2",
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "id": "9",
                        "text": "Isaac Newton"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "10",
                        "text": "Albert Einstein"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "11",
                        "text": "Benjamin Franklin"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "12",
                        "text": "Marie Curie"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "text": "What now-ubiquitous device was invented by Zenith engineer Eugene Polley in 1955?",
                "type": "1",
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "id": "13",
                        "text": "Microwave oven"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "14",
                        "text": "Remote control"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "5",
                "text": "What Benjamin Franklin invented?",
                "type": "1",
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "id": "15",
                        "text": "Bifocal spectacles"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "16",
                        "text": "Radio"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I can able to get all data's from this response by using the following code, unfortunately i can't show the answer set for the suitable questions.

my code snippet is,

```
public void getQuestions(String survey_response) {
    try {
        JSONObject first_obj = new JSONObject(survey_response);
        String data_stirng = first_obj.getString("data");
        JSONObject sub_obj = new JSONObject(data_stirng);
        String name_val = sub_obj.getString("questions");
        JSONArray questions_array = new JSONArray(name_val);
        for (int i = 0; i < questions_array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject qus_elements = questions_array.getJSONObject(i);
            QUESTION_ID = qus_elements.getString("id");
            QUESTION_TEXT = qus_elements.getString("text");
            QUESTION_TYPE = qus_elements.getString("type");
            String answers_val = qus_elements.getString("answers");
            JSONArray ans_array = new JSONArray(answers_val);
            Log.v("Answers Array Values", ans_array + "");
            for (int j = 0; j < ans_array.length(); j++) {

                JSONObject ans_elements = ans_array.getJSONObject(j);
                ANSWERS_ID = ans_elements.getString("id");
                ANSWERS_TEXT = ans_elements.getString("text");
                answers_id.add(ANSWERS_ID);
                answers_text.add(ANSWERS_TEXT);
            }

            ques_id.add(QUESTION_ID);
            ques_text.add(QUESTION_TEXT);
            ques_type.add(QUESTION_TYPE);
        }
        // Log.v("QUESTION ID ARRAY", ques_id + "");
        // Log.v("QUESTION Text ARRAY", ques_text + "");
        // Log.v("QUESTION type ARRAY", ques_type + "");
        Log.v("ANSWERS ID ARRAY", answers_id + "");
        Log.v("ANSWERS TEXT ARRAY", answers_text + "");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I need to show this response like this, i doesn't know how to show the set of question and answers in this format.

[image: sktech]

Comment: @Houcine: You need the array list?

Comment: i need just to see if you retreive jsonArrays properly :). 
Note: you can directy use json.getJsonObject(String key); and json.getJsonArray(String key); instead of getting the String and instanciate the JsonObject/JsonArray with that string

Comment: the parsing is OK , your problem is how to display your data which you stock in Sets ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use two beans like this : 
Question :

```
public class Question {
  private int id;
  private String text;
  private int type;
  private ArrayList<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();

  public Question( int id, String text, int type, ArrayList<Answer> answers) {
     this.id = id;
     this.text = text;
     this.type = type;
     this.answers = answers;
  }
  //TODO Getters and Setters
}
```

Answer :

```
public class Answer {
  private int id;
  private String text;

  public Answer(int id, String text) {
     this.id = id;
     this.text = text;
  }
  //TODO Getters and Setters
}
```

and in your parsing of Questions and Answers do this :

```
ArrayList<Question> listQuestions = new ArrayList<Question>();

    JSONArray questions_array = sub_obj.getJsonArray("questions");
            for (int i = 0; i < questions_array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonQuestion = questions_array.getJSONObject(i);
                Question q = new Question();
                q.setId(jsonQuestion.optInt("id",-1));
                q.setText(jsonQuestion.optString("text",null));
                q.setType(jsonQuestion.optInt("type",-1));
                JSONArray ans_array = jsonQuestion.getJsonArray("answers");
                Log.v("Answers Array Values", ans_array + "");
                for (int j = 0; j < ans_array.length(); j++) {

                    JSONObject jsonAnswer = ans_array.getJSONObject(j);
                    Answer a = new Answer();
                    a.setId(jsonAnswer.optInt("id",-1);
                    a.setText(jsonAnswer.optString("text"),null);
                    q.getAnswers().add(a);
                }

                listQuestions.add(q);
            }
```

And then you have all your `Questions` in the `listQuestions` ; all what you have to do is adding a loop `For` and you will get your questions , and each question have its own answers via `q.getAnswers()` like this :

```
for(int l = 0; l< listQuestions.size(); l++ ){
   Question currentQuestion = listQuestions.get(l);
   Log.i("QCMActivity", "the Question : "+currentQuestion.getText());
   ArrayList<Answer> answersOfCurrentQuestion = currentQuestion.getAnswers();
   Log.i("QCMActivity", "Answers : ");
   for( int k = 0; k< answersOfCurrentQuestion.size(); k++) {
       Answer currentAnswer = answersOfCurrentQuestion.get(k);
       Log.i("QCMActivity", "Option "+(k+1)+" : "+currentAnswer.getText());
   }
}
```

Comment: @Hocine: it working fine, when i print the answer i got like this, 11-10 08:46:49.790: V/Answers Array Values(9709): [com.fsp.acacia.health.Week_Assesment_Activity$Answer@41474e60, com.fsp.acacia.health.Week_Assesment_Activity$Answer@41474ee8, com.fsp.acacia.health.Week_Assesment_Activity$Answer@41474f28, com.fsp.acacia.health.Week_Assesment_Activity$Answer@41474f68]
how can i get the actual string.

Comment: i've edited my answer to add the way to display data from an ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things that you can do to achieve this.

1. Have a simple model class like

   ```
   class Entry{
       String question;
       String[] options;
   }
   //Hold all your parsed entries to the array list
   ArrayList entries;
   ```
2. For making the UI, now you can iterate with every 'Entry' and display the options using Text View and Radio Buttons.
   -So you can manage the whole question'are in either a single ViewGroup or have separate Navigation

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Could you please explain little bit more,

Comment: Assuming that you are through with the step1 (let me know if you are stuck at it itself) and now you have the whole JSON parsed and added to the ArrayList. There on ... for UI what you can do is ... If you have the Question and Answers 1 page per question - launch the QuestionActivity by passing an Intent with `Integer` extra. check the presence of value -it would tell you the `index` of the question you want to show. So, from your static ArrayList - retrieve that `Entry`. On the UI - prepare a RelativeLayout with TextView for question and RadioGroup for the Answers.

Comment: And then you can do `textView.setText(entry.question)` and similarly the answers in the `options[]` can be set to the RadioGroup. For navigation again launch the same activity but this time in the intent do `putExtra Integer of ++index` that you reviced in `onCreate` of current activity instance

Comment: may i know your concept is same as above answer

Comment: Yes, its elaboration on the steps from the above answer

Comment: Kindly look at Houcine's answer, it will works fine, the i get the array list which is i posted an comment, could you please tell me how can i get it an actual string

Comment: From @Houcine answer, if you have `getters and setters` like `getText getId` . Then in `for(int i=0;i<question.getAnswers().size();i++){System.out.println(question.getAnswers().get(i).getText());}` will print all the strings